# Angular - Can ng-messages have an or statement?

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 input fields, if either one of them is empty I want an error message to show. I'm trying to use `||` but it doesnt work - is this allowed in 'ng-messages'?

Code:

```
<div ng-messages="postForm.o1.$error || postForm.o2.$error"
   ng-if="postForm.o1.$touched || postForm.o2.$touched">
   <span ng-message="required">at least 2 are required</span>
</div>
```

And the input itself;

```
<input name="o1" ng-model="main.o1ToAdd" type="text"
          placeholder="Yes" required/>

<input name="o2" ng-model="main.o2ToAdd" type="text"
          placeholder="Yes" required/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use || in `ng-messages`. The value of ng-messages is expected to be an object, each key representing a boolean.

```
{
  required: false,
  minlength: true,
  customErrorCondition: false
}
```

As a workaround to evaluate multiple conditions, you can use this

```
<div ng-messages="{ required: !main.o1ToAdd || !main.o2ToAdd }"
   ng-if="postForm.o1.$touched || postForm.o2.$touched">
   <!-- This message is shown when either of the inputs is missing -->
   <span ng-message="required">at least 2 are required</span>
</div>
```

Edit: Added [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wjJ8TNtbZUkawnfbXIxj?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution:

```
<p ng-show="postForm.o1.$error.required || postForm.o2.$error.required">
    at least 2 are required
</p>
```